# Firebase DatabaseException Issue Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get value name and phone as a name ="name", phone="123456". How can I solve it ?

My Database Structure : Users/Drivers (name="Name", phone="123456")

My Rider Class:

```
public class Rider {
private  String name,email,password,phone;

public Rider(){}

public Rider(String name, String phone){

     this.name=name;
     this.phone=phone;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}


public void setName(String name){

    this.name=name;

}

public void setPhone(String phone){

    this.phone=phone;

}
```

My Activity Class:

```
  public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("Drivers")
                    .child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Rider rider=dataSnapshot.getValue(Rider.class);

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()))
                            .flat(true)
                            .title(rider.getName())
                            .snippet("phone:"+rider.getPhone())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_car_background)));
                }
```

Error :  ***com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String***

Comment: Are you positive that `phone` in your database is a string and not actually a number?  In the console, does it have quotation marks or not?

Comment: My phone value is  "123456" , name value is "Michael".

Comment: can you post a photo of your database ? thanks

Comment: @GastónSaillén  https://imgur.com/Gl1Ebkg

Comment: Yeah, so, you have a string value for phone, but you're trying to force it into a number field.  You can't do that - the types have to match.

Comment: @DougStevenson  How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: Make sure the types match.  If your data object wants a string, make sure you have a string in the database.  If your data objects wants a Long, make sure you have a number in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that in `FirebaseDatabase` is stored as a `Long` value. You could check and replace these values in the database or you coulc create another setter in the model class to accept `Long` values. Then, you could use `String.valueOf()` method to store the value in the private field.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, FirebaseDatabase is stored as a string value. Because my name value is "Juanje", not Juanje

Answer (score 0):

I thinkt that the problem is that you DIDN'T added your phone number between "" inside Firebase DB. This means that Firebase will see that value as a Long, and you want it to be a String according to the code that you provided.

Instead add the values in Firebase DB console like this:

```
phone="123456"
```

[image]

In my pic I wanted the number to be an Integer or Long.

If you want to change the value in Firebase Console, just click on the value and start editing.

Comment: So, how can I change name value like phone=123456 ? I can't change.

Comment: @MichaelSouza can you post a print screen of your Firebase console database  so that we can see how you defined the values there?

Comment: @MichaelSouza the problem is exactly the one that I thought...you have a number in the DB, because the number is not between quotation marks ("") and in the Java code you have the phone number defined as a String

Answer (score 0):

As I can see , in your database you have phone in some keys that is not phone = "19485" but instead is phone = 3947. Change in those places that are without the " " , for the " " . You can edit them manually from Firebase

Comment: I have 350 record as a driver. I can't change value manually for all of them.

Comment: There are values that are not strong but they have been added as longs first, you should do some sort of loop that changes all of those to string, either way when you parse them you are parsing ponga with a string model , that's where you get the error

Comment: Your error is from firebase side and not from your code

Answer (score 0):

You have no problems with rider class. Your problem Relevant to the child value type in the Firebase database

child  value with  => ""   its string value
if not have "" , its integer value

Your Constructor function parameters types String yes its okey but your  Constructor function parameters types same Firebase database child value type .
I have issue like yours and i fixed this issue => change child value 123456 to "123456"
Finally your fixed this issue